# strftime(%Z) returns wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have this date

```
date = Mon, 15 Aug 2016 13:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

which is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class

Then, I need to get the time in time zone "Fiji"

```
start_in_time_zone = date.in_time_zone("Fiji")
```

This returns `Tue, 16 Aug 2016 01:00:00 +12 +12:00`

Then, I need to present the date with the name of the time zone, so

```
time_zone_abbr = start_in_time_zone.strftime("%Z")
```

It should return `"FJT"`

but returns `"+12"`

Any idea why?

I am using `ruby 2.3.7` and `rails 4.2.7`

**UPDATE**

If I do

```
start_in_time_zone = date.in_time_zone("Madrid")
```

it returns

```
"CEST"
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried to see where the problem is by setting different time.

```
date=Time.utc(2018, 07, 25, 20, 30, 45)
date.class #=> Time
date.in_time_zone("Madrid") #=> Wed, 25 Jul 2018 22:30:45 CEST +02:00
date.in_time_zone("Fiji") #=> Thu, 26 Jul 2018 08:30:45 +12 +12:00
date.in_time_zone("EST") #=> Wed, 25 Jul 2018 15:30:45 EST -05:00
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there is no `in_time_zone` method defined on any date/time class in Ruby.

Comment: I have updated my question. The date is ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone class

Comment: You should probably update tags, There is no such class `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` in [tag:ruby].

Comment: Right. Done that now.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Well, it's OS X. Note: it should work on Circle Ci servers so it should be platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it seems there is no 'FJT' abbreviation assigned to 'Fiji' in timezone data used by Rails. Also, support for those abbreviations seems patchy regarding Pacific timezones.

```
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Samoa').strftime('%Z')
=> "+13"
irb(main):003:0> DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Midway Island').strftime('%Z')
=> "SST"
irb(main):004:0> DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Samoa').strftime('%Z')
=> "+13"
irb(main):005:0> DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Tokelau Is.').strftime('%Z')
=> "+13"
irb(main):006:0> DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Wellington').strftime('%Z')
=> "NZST"
```

UTC offset is displayed as fallback. If it's any help, remember that full name and additional information can be retrieved with `.time_zone.tzinfo` on `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects. 'FJ' code is recognized by [`TZInfo::Country`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Country).

```
irb(main):056:0> TZInfo::Country.get('FJ')
=> #<TZInfo::Country: FJ>
irb(main):057:0> TZInfo::Country.get('FJ').zone_info
=> [#<TZInfo::CountryTimezone: Pacific/Fiji>]
```